# Use blob storage for temporary storage for PUT

Tags: ithit-webdav-server

I am working on adapting IT HIT WebDAV server for use with a Microsoft Azure Website. I am struggling with a problem. I need to have the file uploaded and sent directly to BLOB storage, and not to a temporary file on local disk. The reason is that local disk space is limited.

Is there a way I can redirect a file being sent via PUT into blob storage?

Thank you!

-Eric

PS. Azure Websites run IIS 8.x

Comment: Are you sure you want to use BLOB as storage? I would rethink my storage strategy at that point.

Comment: Totally the way to go. BLOB storage is cheap and plentiful. Plus highly redundant.  Azure Websites only have a limited amount of local space. Our storage needs are rather large.

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179451.aspx) is what you're doing now, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what we're using, but using the .Net libraries to do it.  See: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using [samples](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/server_examples/) provided with IT Hit WebDAV Server Engine or code generated by [WebDAV Wizards for Visual Studio](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/vs_wizards).

To keep your documents in the storage that is different from MS SQL or file system you need to change the implementation of [IFile](http://doc3.webdavsystem.com/default.aspx?main=http://doc3.webdavsystem.com/ITHit.WebDAV.Server.Class1.IFile.html) and [IFolder](http://doc3.webdavsystem.com/default.aspx?main=http://doc3.webdavsystem.com/ITHit.WebDAV.Server.Class1.IFolder.html) interfaces as well as implementation of [DavContextBase.GetHierarchyItem](http://doc3.webdavsystem.com/ITHit.WebDAV.Server.DavContextBase.GetHierarchyItem.html) method.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That's what I'm doing, is implementing my own iFile and IFolder classes.  Nice to hear I am on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: Question, though, is regarding the temp file. The documentation seems to suggest that with IIS 8 there is no temporary file used? Is that true?

Comment: Temp file is not created in case of ASP.NET 4.0 pool (unbuffered upload). In case of ASP.NET 2.0 pool or VS Dev Server, to avoid upload buffering use the ITHitPutUploadProgressAndResumeModule. The web.config generated by WebDAV Wizard for VS (as well as samples)  contains options that enables unbuffered upload for both ASP.NET 2.0 and 4.0 pool.